# Getting rid of offset in hall sensors

Tags: hall-effect

I would like to know how it is possible to remove (external) offsets like temperature and unwanted magnetic fields when using a hall sensor.
As far as I know this should basically be possible by using several hall sensors and rearrange them in a certain way.
I think it is even possible to swap the current and hall connectors but I'm not sure about that.
Note: In my documents (which are in a different language) this principle is under the term

> spinning current principle

but when I google that it looks way more like a special solid physics effect or so.

Comment: I think you are leaving out the context in which these hall sensors are used.

Comment: that was fast, sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Well, what are these being used for? Offsets for what?

Comment: depends on the application but mainly to measure a magnetic field. Or to measure a current? Offsets might occur due to temperature or magnetic influences and so on which are not wanted to be taken into account.

Comment: Oh, so just offests in the sensors themselves. I think you can do that just by placing one beside or underneath the other facing in the opposite direction, much like how you periodically turn a gyrocompass upside down. But these are for internal offsets. External offsets are something else altogether.

Comment: true, that's also possible. But are two already sufficient to eliminate (any) offsets? It's a bit difficult to separate between external and internal offsets, or? In case of temperature, it is almost everywhere and an internal/external magnetic field is also questionable as the sensor is meant to measure an (external) magnetic field.
I'm just thinking loud as I try to separate the involved effects and circumstances.

Comment: Much improved question!